# How to count similar values in two columns of string type based on a condition in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set where :

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6867 entries, 1 to 6867
Data columns (total 13 columns):

## Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   collection_date   6867 non-null   datetime64[ns]
1   urban_rural       6867 non-null   object
2   education         6867 non-null   object
3   income            6867 non-null   object
4   Vote_Now          6867 non-null   object
5   Past_Vote         6867 non-null   object
6   CM_satisfaction   6867 non-null   object
7   MLA_satisfaction  6867 non-null   object
8   age               6867 non-null   int64
9   gender            6867 non-null   object
10  assembly_no       6867 non-null   int64
11  category          6867 non-null   object
12  weight            6867 non-null   float64
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(1), int64(2), object(9)

I wanted to get count of similar values in two of the columns 'Vote_now' and 'Past_Vote'.

```
survey.where(survey[['Vote_Now', 'Past_Vote']] == "RJD").count()
```

and

```
survey.where(survey['Vote_Now'] == survey['Past_Vote'] == "RJD").count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For count matched values, it means count `True`s values use `sum` without `where`:

```
(survey[['Vote_Now', 'Past_Vote']] == "RJD").sum()
```

Comment: @RishiPandey - Supeeer, happy coding!